# Rsync NTFS and SMB share not working

Tags: rsync, ntfs, nas

I'm struggling with my rsync script to sync data (on Ubuntu) from an NTFS drive to a NAS share.

What I do:

1. Mount the NAS share:
   `sudo mount -t cifs -o user=$DST_USER,password=$DST_USERPW,rw,uid=$DST_USER $DST_SHARE $DST_MNT`
2. Rync:
   `rsync --recursive --times --modify-window=3601 --verbose --progress --delete --compress --copy-links --backup --exclude ".@__thumb" --backup-dir=$DST_MNT/$HISTORY_NAME/$DATE --files-from=/$BAK_CONFIG/include.txt $SRC $DST_LOCAL | tee $HISTORY/rsync_sync_$DATE.log`

My issue is that whatever I do the files get synced all the time.
I have read that such within NTFS, -a is not working and -t should be used instead. Also the modify time should be set, which I did even set to 1h+. But still: the files in the target folder get synced every time I execute the script and get the timestamp of the last syncing.

I have tried as well it via the checksum mechanism but this is awfully slow.

Any idea I can do to get it running? Sorry for bothering you guys with yet another post about that but I don't find my issue...

Thanks in advance for your support!